# participation constraint demonstrated in translation relationship

Tags: sql, entity-relationship

I'm self=studying textbook Database Management Systems, 3rd edition. In Chapter 3.5.4, author talkis about participation constraints captured in a translation relationship. They show an example with participation constraint that every department must have a manager:

[ERD for Managers and Works_In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eq4d.jpg)

They then say a translation relationship with the first approach can't capture the constraint that every department must have a manager:

[SQL CREATE TABLE for translation relationship with first approach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uipig.jpg)

The author further asks the reader to think what effect it would have if we added NOT NULL constraints to the `ssn` and `did` fields. They give the hint

> The constraint would prevent the firing of manager, but does not ensure that manager is initially appointed for each department.

Why can't the first translation relationship capture the participation constraint even if we put NOT NULL after `ssn`?

What is their further request thinking?

Maybe these two are related.

Comment: Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. Put what is needed to ask in your post, quoting with credit & formatting & relating to your question. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL--text.

Answer (score 0):

> The author further asks the reader to think what effect it would have if we added NOT NULL constraints to the `ssn` and `did` fields.

Actually the author requests that the reader make such a mind construction for external table Manages described in 3.5.3. For Manages such a constraint wouldn't be much help indeed since not every department may reference a manager. But in table Dept_Mgr described in 3.5.4 we build a link to a manager into a department entity itself, and preventing it from being null works.

Comment: Thank you for your effort to answer my question. But in example 3.5.3, "did" is the primary key and foreign key in "manages" which captures participation constraint. And if we put NOT NULL after ssn in example 3.5.3, does it shows every department references a manager?  @NLink

Comment: It's all about different entities. Table "Manages" in 3.5.3 describes the entity "link from departments to employees". So, all restrictions on that table influences only "link" itself: 1) every link must point at existing department 2) every link must point at existing employee 3) there may be no two links pointing at same department. We can not check condition "every department must have a manager" by adding restrictions to "link".

Comment: But in second example in 3.5.3 (same in 3.5.4) we're adding constraints to table "Dept_Mgr", which replaces table "Departments". So, table "Dept_Mgr" describes the entity "department". And restrictions on that table make a bit different set of rules: 1) there may be no two departments with same did's 2) every department must point at some employee 3) that employee should exist. Another words, when we build link into entity table we are becoming able to check entity params. @nwdsl

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments.